# Relationship problem?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have four tables

```
Tag=>id,tag_name

Image=>Id,Image_name

TagImage=>Id,tag_id,Image_id


ImageStudent=id,Image_id,student_id
```

And I want to find a record using student id and tag name. What relationship do I use?

Comment: I'd start by setting them up on a date, then see how they go from there.

Comment: What record are you trying to find? An image Record? Are you asking how you would use a JOIN to get the record you need? Also is the TagImage table really needed?

Comment: I'm guessing the model associations are `Tag HABTM Image` and `Student HABTM Image` (there's no `Student` model provided, but it has to be there). The `TagImage` and `ImageStudent` are "magic" models that create HABTM relationships in Cake's ORM: `Tag hasMany TagImage`/`TagImage belongsTo Tag` and `Image hasMany TagImage/`TagImage belongsTo Image`.

Comment: @Andy +1 for sense of humor :D

Comment: The problem with Andy's answer if there isn't any referential integrity, you could end up in a denormalized relationship.

Comment: I create model help of your answer sir but it not working ..!can you explain me in details how HABTM relationship gibven in model ...plz –

Comment: The SQL query by mmattax is working but is there a way to do it using find?

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to use a UNION with a query like this, here it is with the necessary joins.

```
SELECT Image.* FROM Image 
INNER JOIN ImageStudent ON Image.Id = ImageStudent.Image_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TagImage ON Image.Id = TagImage.Image_id
INNER JOIN Tag ON TagImage.Id = Tag.Id
WHERE Tag.tag_name = 'foo' AND ImageStudent.student_id = 42;
```

Comment: All things are perfectly nice? Thanks 
Can u tell me in details of referential integrity??what is that?

Comment: I create model help of your answer sir but it not working ..!can hu explain me in details how HABTM relationship gibven in model ...plz

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific with your questions, you're making this sound like it's your homework... You can get clues to the relationships by the JOINS I used in the query (OUTER vs. INNER)

Comment: Tag=>id,tag_name

Image=>Id,Image_name

TagImage=>Id,tag_id,Image_id


ImageStudent=id,Image_id,student_id

Student = id ,fname ,lname,

Given by your query its work but not give right result..?

Can help how i join above table ?

i want to find image by using tag_name and student_id

Comment: To mmattax sir
I want to create taging system tag on photo and also tag on image using student id how i create database table and how i handle relationship in cakephp plz sir help me ........plz
thanks